# Angular - setValue FormControl return [object ErrorEvent] thrown

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a Form that has a FormControl:

```js
this.description = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(250)]);

this.adForm = new FormGroup({
  description: this.description
});
```

The HTML representation of the FormControl is:

```html
<label for="description">Description</label>
<input formControlName="description" id="description" class="form-control description" type="text" placeholder="Description">
```

And I'm coding a test to validate the FormControl.
The test is like:

```js
const descriptionControl = component.adForm.controls['description'];
descriptionControl.setValue('longDescription-longDescription-longDescription-longDescription-');
fixture.detectChanges();
```

I'm using the method "setValue" to set the value of the input.
The problem is that with some values the method return:

```
[object ErrorEvent] thrown
```

This is the image of the error:

[image]

- If I put descriptionControl.setValue('descriptio'); It works
  fine, not return the error.
- If I put descriptionControl.setValue('description'); return  [object
  ErrorEvent] thrown
- If I put a long value like this:
  descriptionControl.setValue('description-description-description-description-description-description-description-description-description-description-description-description-description-description-description-description-description-description-description-description-description-description-'); It works fine, not return the error.

What is happening, or am I using the method in the wrong way?

Comment: What do you mean by returning `[object ErrorEvent] thrown`, `AbstractControl.setValue()` does not return anything

Comment: @Dummy you are right. That is the error shown by the console.

Comment: You need to provide more information about the error

Comment: @Dummy I've put an image with all the description that I get of the error.

Comment: It is a failed test or the code throws an exception somewhere? If it is a failed test, then you just have to figure out why

Comment: @Dummy me method "setValue" throws the exception. But it depends of the value as I describe above. That is the problem.